# Notepad++ regex formula

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm newbie for notepad++. I want to beginning and end of the word of OU keyword.

```
user01,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=local
user02,OU=Security,DC=contoso,DC=local
user03,OU=TEST,OU=HW,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=local
user04,DC=contoso,DC=local
```

My desired output :

```
user01,"OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=local"
user02,"OU=Security,DC=contoso,DC=local"
user03,"OU=TEST,OU=HW,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=local"
user04,"DC=contoso,DC=local"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=,).+$`
- Replace with: `"$0"`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=,)  # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a comma before
.+      # 1 or more any character but newline
$       # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
"$0"    # the whole match surrounded with quotes
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thanks btw , I forgot say. I have updated my question.  DC=contoso,DC=local

Comment: @Cell-o: Sorry but I don't see any update. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: :) I have updated my question

Comment: @Cell-o: OK, see my edit.